# Boost asio getting `Error Code : 125 Operation cancelled`

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was just trying to accept incoming request with **acceptor socket** and when it enters the **async_accept** it throws out an error, I'm not sure what is causing the error. The thing is I'm not even sending the request from the client but still it enters the **async_accept** handler for some reason, here is the part of the code which is causing the error

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>


#include "server.hpp"
#include "connection.hpp"

class Connection;

int main(){
    using Server_ = Server<Connection>;
    auto server = std::make_unique<Server_>(8989);

    server->start();
}
```

server.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

template <typename Connection> 
class Server{
    using shared_connection = std::shared_ptr<Connection>; 

    private:
    unsigned short port_;
    std::thread io_thread_;
    boost::asio::io_context ioc_;
    boost::asio::io_context::work work_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

    void handle_new_request(shared_connection connection, const system::error_code &ec){
        if(!ec){
            connection->start_operation();
        }else{
            error::print(ec);
            return;
        }
    }

    public:
    explicit Server(unsigned short port)
    : acceptor_(ioc_)
    , work_(ioc_)
    , port_(port)
    , endpoint_(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port) { 
        io_thread_ = std::move(std::thread([&]{ ioc_.run(); }));
        io_thread_.join();
    }
    
    ~Server() { 
        if(acceptor_.is_open()) 
            acceptor_.close(); 
        io_thread_.join();
    }

    void start(){
        using namespace asio::ip;

        system::error_code ec;

        // creates an actual operating system socket
        acceptor_.open(endpoint_.protocol(),ec); 
        acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true),ec);
        // binds to the endpoint
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint_,ec); 

        if(!ec){
            std::cout << "Listening for requests from port " << port_ << std::endl;
            acceptor_.listen();
        }else{
            error::print(ec);
            return;
        }

        shared_connection connection = std::make_shared<Connection>(ioc_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(connection->sock_,[=](system::error_code ec){
            handle_new_request(connection,ec);
        });
    }

};
```

connection.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
    using shared_connection = std::shared_ptr<Connection>;
        std::vector<char> buffer_space_;
    private:
        boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 buffer_;
        boost::asio::io_context& ioc_;
    public:
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock_;

        explicit Connection(boost::asio::io_context &context,const int &size = 1024)
            : ioc_(context)
            , sock_(context)
            , buffer_space_(size) 
            , buffer_(buffer_space_.data(),size){}
        
        ~Connection(){ if(sock_.is_open()) sock_.close(); }
        void start_operation(){
            if(sock_.is_open()){
                sock_.async_read_some(buffer_,[me = shared_from_this()](const system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes){
                    if(!ec){
                        for(int i=0;i<bytes;++i)
                            std::cout << me->buffer_space_[i];
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                        me->start_operation();
                    }else{
                        error::print(ec);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
};
```

error.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

namespace error {
    inline void print(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
        std::cerr << "Error Code : " << ec.value() << ", Message : " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

The error lies in having the `io_thread_.run()` in the destructor which would destroy the socket object by then

Comment: Please provide a [mre] at a guess the acceptor is being closed which causes the pending `async_accept` to be cancelled

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes I have made the needed changes. If acceptor is being closed, it means that the server object which owns it is being destroyed I don't think that is the case icause the destructor of the server object has io_thread_.join()

Comment: @Bad_Panda Your server instance is being destroyed when main() exits. Without going through your code, that would cancel all outstanding operations and the thread could then be joined from the destructor.

Comment: @janm Yes I just realized that, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(){
    using Server_ = Server<Connection>;
    auto server = std::make_unique<Server_>(8989);

    server->start();
}
```

`server` will call the deleter, which destroys `Server_` on exiting main. You Would like to join any threads or await the shutdown of the server before exiting main.

You would in your case join the iothread, like you TRIED to do.

However, you do it in the server constructor:

```
explicit Server(unsigned short port)
    : acceptor_(ioc_)
    , work_(ioc_)
    , port_(port)
    , endpoint_(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)
{
    io_thread_ = std::move(std::thread([&] { ioc_.run(); }));
    io_thread_.join();
}
```

> I can't really figure out how this would not hang indefinitely due to the work_. On tangentially related observation is that `work_` is NOT initilaized before `ioc_` (or `thread_`) because initialization happens in order of member declaration instead of order in which the initializers appear. You will want to fix the declaration order regardless:
>
> ```
> boost::asio::io_context ioc_;
> boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
> boost::asio::io_context::work work_;
> unsigned short port_;
> boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint_;
> std::thread io_thread_;
> ```
>
> Similarly in `Connection`:
>
> ```
>   private:
>     boost::asio::io_context& ioc_;
>
>   public:
>     boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock_;
>
>   private:
>     std::vector<char> buffer_space_;
>     boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 buffer_;
> ```

Fixed Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ece4e99933f34ed7)**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

namespace error {
    inline void print(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error Code : " << ec.value()
                  << ", Message : " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
}

#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
    using shared_connection = std::shared_ptr<Connection>;

  private:
    boost::asio::io_context& ioc_;

  public:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock_;

  private:
    std::vector<char> buffer_space_;
    boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 buffer_;

  public:
    explicit Connection(
        boost::asio::io_context& context, const int& size = 1024)
        : ioc_(context)
        , sock_(context)
        , buffer_space_(size)
        , buffer_(buffer_space_.data(), size)
    {
    }

    void start_operation()
    {
        if (sock_.is_open()) {
            sock_.async_read_some(buffer_,
                [me = shared_from_this()](
                    const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes) {
                    if (!ec) {
                        for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes; ++i) {
                            std::cout << me->buffer_space_[i];
                        }
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                        me->start_operation();
                    } else {
                        error::print(ec);
                        return;
                    }
                });
        }
    }
};
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

template <typename Connection> class Server {
    using shared_connection = std::shared_ptr<Connection>;

  private:
    boost::asio::io_context ioc_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>
        work_ {ioc_.get_executor()};
    uint16_t port_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint_;
    std::thread io_thread_;

    void handle_new_request(
        shared_connection connection, const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        if (!ec) {
            connection->start_operation();
        } else {
            error::print(ec);
            return;
        }
    }

  public:
    explicit Server(uint16_t port)
        : acceptor_(ioc_)
        , port_(port)
        , endpoint_(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)
        , io_thread_([&] { ioc_.run(); })
    { ; }

    ~Server()
    {
        if (acceptor_.is_open()) {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            acceptor_.cancel(ec);
            //acceptor_.close(ec);
        }
        work_.reset();
        io_thread_.join();
    }

    void start()
    {
        using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

        boost::system::error_code ec;

        // creates an actual operating system socket
        acceptor_.open(endpoint_.protocol(), ec);
        acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true), ec);
        // binds to the endpoint
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint_, ec);

        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Listening for requests from port " << port_
                      << std::endl;
            acceptor_.listen();
        } else {
            error::print(ec);
            return;
        }

        shared_connection connection = std::make_shared<Connection>(ioc_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            connection->sock_, [=, this](boost::system::error_code ec) {
                handle_new_request(connection, ec);
            });
    }
};

#include <iostream>

//#include "server.hpp"
//#include "connection.hpp"
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class Connection;

int main()
{
    using Server_ = Server<Connection>;
    auto server = std::make_unique<Server_>(8989);

    server->start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(4s);
    // destructor joins
}
```

This would give 4s for the first client to connect, and will shut down as soon as all connections are done.